# How do I execute a standard GCC "configure" script with the TDM64-GCC toolchain?

Tags: c, windows, gcc, configure, tdm-mingw

Which of the executables in the TDM `bin` directory will actually recognize `./configure` as a valid command?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that I am on Windows 8.1, 64-bit. I imagine that makes quite a difference... I've read into it a bit more and it seems that "configure" scripts in general are executed by a set of binaries called "Autotools"? So I suppose my question now is, what would the easiest Windows equivalent to Autotools be?

Answer (score 1):

`./configure` is a shell script.  It will be compatible with bash, sh, and maybe csh.  Probably the first line in it is

```
 #!/bin/sh
```

or

```
 #!/bin/bash
```

If you are not on Linux or Unix, look for a configure script specifically for your operating system.  Not all tools support non-Unix environments.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you should read the `INSTALL` or `README` file included with the sources. Usually they describe all of the available parameters for the `./configure` script (which is not "standard GCC", but specific to the project). For example for the [`strace`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/strace/) project (picked it randomly, as I've cross-compiled it recently), if you want to cross-compile it with your `tdm64-whatever-gcc` toolchain, you have to specify it in the `host` parameter:

```
./configure --host=tdm64-whatever
```